# PHP - Exception Class not found - wrong namespace

Tags: php, moodle, moodle-api

After instantiating moodle "externally" through

```
require_once('../config.php');
```

in a SSO scenario inside an application (namely [MRBS](https://github.com/meeting-room-booking-system/mrbs-code)), i get an error: `Exception - Class "MRBS\Session\context_block" not found` when it comes to find out if the currently logged user has some capability on a specific block:

```
if (has_capability('moodle/block:edit', context_block::instance($blockid)){}
```

I guess it is because the namespace is set to `namespace MRBS\Session;`

How can I correctly refer to `context_block::instance()`?

Moodle functions apparently work (e.g. require_login(), has_capability).
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to either write:

```
if (has_capability('moodle/block:edit', \context_block::instance($blockid)) {}
```

With the '\' character to declare that context_block is in the top-level namespace.

Or you need to put the following at the top of your file:

```
use \context_block;
```

Personally I prefer the first option, but it is generally a matter of personal preference.